# Why isn't there a logging.SUCCESS level?

Tags: python, logging

[Logging levels in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) have numeric values, by which log entries are assigned an order of importance. Some commonly used levels are also assigned human-readable names.

| Level | Numeric Value |
| --- | --- |
| CRITICAL | 50 |
| ERROR | 40 |
| WARNING | 30 |
| INFO | 20 |
| DEBUG | 10 |
| NOTSET | 0 |

Looking at this table, it seems this naming is done in order of *error* severity. This matches, for example, [Windows severity levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/defining-severity-levels) (Critical, Error, Warning, Information, Verbose)

However logging as a concept does not seem to be limited to error logging. The description of the logging tag on Stackoverflow itself, for example, is:

> Computer data logging is the process of recording events in a computer
> program or computer system, usually with a certain scope, in order to
> provide an audit trail that can be used to understand the activity of
> the system and to diagnose problems.

Errors, while important, are not the only important events. When using logging for a complicated and long-running process, successful outcomes can also be important events to know about and record in the log. This leads me to wonder why there is no `logging.SUCCESS` level that is assigned a value above, say, mere warnings (`logging.WARNING`).

Specifically, I have a long-running process where I would not switch on Debug or Info logs in production, but knowing that task identifier x was successfully completed has more value than knowing that subprocess y had a minor recoverable error.

What is the pythonic way to log an interim successful event that is an important milestone in code execution?
(Or is `logging.INFO` itself the correct way to log success?)

Comment: I believe it takes the happy path of assuming that things will work, in which case `info` would suffice for logging success events.

Comment: This one: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial says that INFO corresponds to "Confirmation that things are working as expected." Which, I guess, means success.

Comment: `logging.SUCCESS` would basically be the same as `logging.INFO` IMO.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the log levels map to error severity at all. Only half of them do, but the other half simply describe how important the information is ("debug" would be a weird error severity). And for the first three " how important the information is" maps simply nicely onto " error severity".

Comment: I am thinking of a long running process where knowing that task identifier x was successfully completed has more value than knowing that subprocess y had a minor recoverable error. Ergo in that case that `SUCCESS` has higher priority than a mere `WARNING`.

Comment: @Pranab Why would it have more value? If I'm looking for problems or want to check service health, the first step is very rarely to wade through all the "everything is fine" messages.

Comment: @Voo great question. On reflection, it's because I am using logging as a progress log and, while debugging, refactoring or optimizing, I want to navigate progress through various system interactions by looking at the log. I seem to be using successful events in the log as milestones for navigating code progress, like a post-facto print() debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logging` built-in module motivation is described in [PEP 282](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/), which regarding [levels](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/#levels) after enumerating them says:

> Although the above levels are strongly recommended, the logging system should not be prescriptive. Users may define their own levels, as well as the textual representation of any levels. User defined levels must, however, obey the constraints that they are all positive integers and that they increase in order of increasing severity. User-defined logging levels are supported through two module-level functions:

```
def getLevelName(lvl):
        """Return the text for level 'lvl'."""
        ...

def addLevelName(lvl, lvlName):
        """
        Add the level 'lvl' with associated text 'levelName', or
        set the textual representation of existing level 'lvl' to be
        'lvlName'."""
        ...
```

Therefore I suggest firstly to carefully consider if one of already defined can not be used. If it can not then use `logging.addLevelName` function for creating custom level.